# How to loop through multiple values in a dictionary to create a long list in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

Just wondering if there is an easy way to create a list of filenames from different values in a dictionary. For example:

```
thisdict = {
  "V": [20,40,60,80],
  "F": [0.1,0.2],
  "T": [4,3]
}
totalRuns = 1
for val in thisdict.keys():
    totalRuns = totalRuns*len(thisdict[val])

fileList = ['Run_Name']*totalRuns
```

The end goal to have a list of string outputs like:

Run_Name_20V_0.1F_4T,
Run_Name_40V_0.1F_4T,
Run_Name_60V_0.1F_4T,
Run_Name_80V_0.1F_4T,
Run_Name_20V_0.2F_4T,
Run_Name_40V_0.2F_4T,
Run_Name_60V_0.2F_4T,
Run_Name_80V_0.2F_4T,
Run_Name_20V_0.1F_3T,
Run_Name_40V_0.1F_3T,
Run_Name_60V_0.1F_3T,
Run_Name_80V_0.1F_3T,
Run_Name_20V_0.2F_3T,
Run_Name_40V_0.2F_3T,
Run_Name_60V_0.2F_3T,
Run_Name_80V_0.2F_3T

Since we have 4 for V, 2 for F and 2 for T, we would want a list of size 16 (4x2x2)

Thanks!

Comment: Look at `itertools.product`.

Comment: `files = [f'Run_Name_{v}V_{f}F_{t}T' for v,f,t in itertools.product(*thisdict.values())]`